# Replay button script in unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on an android app in unity it's allowed the user to enter voice or text(through the text field) then the user will get the animation that matches with the word entered by the character, also there is a repeat button that replay the animation if the user touches the button.
but now I am stuck in the repeat button code and I don't know where is the mistake.

Comment: I want the repeat button work and replay the animation but it doesn't.

Comment: It is not working at all? Did you set the logs (e.g. `Debug.Log("OnGUI() is called");)` in OnGUI() method? Is it called?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add listener to the button in `Start()` method:

```
void Start () {
    gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        var animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        animator.Play("BeginMove");
    });
}
```

Comment: in this line:                                          SomeButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
{

Comment: You need to get the instance of the button and add listener to it. Something like in my edited answer.

Comment: I tried that but this error shown at the console:                                          MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animator' attached to the "Button (2)" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Animator to the game object "Button (2)". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Comment: I fix this problem by adding the animator component to the button Inspector... but the repeat button still did not work when I pressing it nothing happened, please if anyone knows how can I fix that help me.

Comment: is there another solution or code I can try it instead of what I write?

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: maybe your Animation State Machine is not configured properly.

Comment: how can I know?

Comment: maybe docs will help you https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationSection.html. It's hard to say without seeing the project.

Comment: do you think my repeat button code is written by correct way or should I change something in unity scene or in event system for the button?

Comment: You can set logs and you will see what's wrong. E.g. set logs to OnClick method and look if it is called. If it is called then you have to config animation scene, if it is not called - the problem in button event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to get the reference of the object which has animator component attached to it.
You're trying to get the animator component from the button script, is the animator component attached to the gameobject?
      Try this

```
    public words CurrentObjectWithAnimator; //Take Reference for Animator


        void OnGUI()
          {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 50, 30), "Replay"))
            {
              //CurrentObjectWithAnimator = GameObject.Find("Current object with animator");
                var animator = CurrentObjectWithAnimator.GetComponent<Animator>();
                animator.Play("BeginMove");
            }
            }
           }
```

Comment: are you sure I have to use OnGUI while I create the button on the scene!